# show folders and subfolders inside a sidebar

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

i have a folder 'server' and inside of server i have anothers folders 'computer1' and 'computer2' and inside of computer1 i have more folder and inside of computer2 i have more folders too

So i have a sidebar and until now i put this to show the computer1 and computer2

```
<ul class="nav side-menu">
             <?php

              foreach (glob('server/sandro/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)as$subfolder) {
                  echo '<li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i>'. basename($subfolder) .'<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>';
                  echo '<ul class="nav child_menu">';
                  echo '</ul>';
                  echo '</li>';
              }

             ?>
            </ul>
```

and well..it's result, but now i want to add inside of 
     `echo '<ul class="nav child_menu">';
      echo '</ul>';`

the rest of subfolders that are inside of the computer1 and computer2

please, help-me.

Comment: Just repeat the command but using `$subfolder` instead of the * in the `foreach` command

Comment: I make this, but nothing change, it's the same if I put with *

Comment: show the code so we can see where it goes wrong

Comment: You want a recursive function, which is a function that calls itself. In your case for every 'parent' directory it finds you want to call the same function on its 'child' directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to use `function` and call function in itself

```
<ul class="nav side-menu">

<?php
function foldersList($folderName = NULL) {

$return = '';

foreach (glob('./server/sandro/' . $folderName . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $subfolder) {

    // call function to check subfolders - don't forget write `/`
    $subFolders = foldersList(basename($subfolder). '/');

    $return .= '<li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i>' . basename($subfolder) . '<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>';
    $return .= '<ul class="nav child_menu">';

    // if subfolder exist add to return variable
    $return .= $subFolders != '' ? $subFolders : '';

    $return .= '</ul>';
    $return .= '</li>';
   }

   return $return;
}

echo foldersList();
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey, thank you. But now, I don't know what appens, but when i  put (glob('./' .$FolderName.... it's work
but if I change to glob('server/sandro/' . $FolderName....appears the computer1 and the computer2 but not the respective subfolders

Comment: If you write `(glob('./' .$FolderName....` it will read folders and subfolders where your php file located.

Comment: @Sandromedeiros is 'server/' your `root` folder on the computer or in the server?

Comment: but I want (glob('server/sandro/' ..... and read the folders and subfolders of  /server/sandro/

Comment: It is mean, your .php file is not located in `server/sandro` yes?

Comment: no it's not located
my website it's like this:
-build
-css
-js
-images
-server
index.php
login.php
logout.php
etc...

and the server paste it's like this
-server:
      -sandro
               -computer1
                      another folders
               -computer2
                      another folders

Comment: if i put (glob('./' ...... appears all the folders including server/sandro/computer1 and computer2/another folders

but if I put (glob('server/sandro').....appears computer1 and computer2 but i can't make a dropdown and the the another folders

It's hard to explain by writing, but i hope you understand

Comment: I couldn't understand where located your script and where are you trying to read folders, I understand only that, you want to get only that folders which located in computer1 and computer2, do you? Did you tried php scandir?

Comment: I take printscreens, for you understand..i'm going to lunch, so wait.
http://imgur.com/a/CotRo

Comment: tell me something please

Comment: I understand you must write like this - `(glob('./server/sandro' ......` or if your all links run in index.php write like this `(glob(__DIR__ . '/server' ......` try and let me know

Comment: appears the computer1 and computer2, but not makes the dropdown and don't show the other folders.
like I show in http://imgur.com/a/CotRo

Comment: @Sandromedeiros do you using TeamViewer?

Comment: can you please access again? I have another problem...sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143884/discussion-between-teymur-mardaliyer-lennon-and-sandromedeiros).

Comment: hey, can you give me your email again please? i lost